# Objective-C sort alphabetically nsarray with localized Japanese?

Tags: objective-c, unicode, localization, nsarray

Is the name of localized "jp" or "jap"

in

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"jp or jap"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Comment: Please specify your question in more detail.

Comment: I lived there for five years, and I can tell you it is probably not "jap". That is a derogatory term left over from WWII...

Comment: @paul I did not know. Thanks for correcting it/me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"ja_JP"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give feedback today.

Comment: it works :) by the way, where do I find a list of such values for AppleLanguages?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your array as following

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

`localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` is method in [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Comment: you are right, but how should I sort according to local languages?

Comment: What I have mentioned will sort according to local languages. Please check the doc for `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`. Thats why I have given the link.

Comment: but where do I set local language? and how do I set local language? That is my question.

Comment: You can set the language in iPhone/iPad/iPod  Settings->General->Internationalization

Comment: but how to set it programmatically?